# Generate html email body in Azure Function

Tags: azure, templates, azure-functions, html-email

In my application, I need to send templated HTML emails from an Azure Function.

- The content is fairly large and getting the HTML to work in all clients can be pretty hard, even with the help of something like https://litmus.com/pre-send-testing. For this reason, I do not want to to use string concatenation/interpolation. I want to have the email content in a file I can view/edit in an IDE.
- I need to replace some content with text for the specific recipient.
- Ideally, I would like to have conditional logic in the template to avoid too much duplication (although this is not essential).

I have used the excellent https://github.com/toddams/RazorLight nuget package in other environments but unfortunately it [does not work in Azure Fucntions](https://github.com/toddams/RazorLight#razorlight-does-not-work-properly-on-aws-lambda-or-azure-functions).

**Are there any other solutions for text templating for HTML that work in Azure Functions?**

At the moment my best option is something like this (where Body.html is an embedded resource file):

```
StringBuilder body = new StringBuilder();
Stream template = this.GetType().Assembly.GetManifestResourceStream("EmailTemplating.Body.html");
using var reader = new StreamReader(template, Encoding.UTF8);
body.Append(reader.ReadToEnd());

body.Replace("{{recipient-name}}", "Jim");
```

Answer (score 1):

In the end, we used https://github.com/rexm/Handlebars.Net which has good templating features (standard Moustache/Handlebars functionality) and worked a charm in Azure Functions.

Answer (score 0):

Did you consider storage for the purpose? You can store a template file say template.html in a blob container and leverage it whenever required (download the file into a MemoryStream and make the Stream the content of the Function’s response/ the content for the next action based on your reqirement.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. That'd be another valid place to store the template.

I think perhaps my original question wasn't very clear. My problem was not where to retrieve the template from but rather how to replace values in the template without writing my own templating engine, especially when it comes to having partial templates for hearers and footers etc. or having conditional logic in them.